# React, set body style conditionally by adding a class related to a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following, where I am trying to change the body style while the image is uploading (so the user knows it is uploading). How can I attach a class to the body while the image is uploading and then remove it once the image has uploaded?

```
const [uploadingImage, setUploadingImage] = useState(false)

    const uploadToFirebase = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (image) {
          const storageRef = storage.ref(`${user1}/${tripid}/documents`);
          const imageRef = storageRef.child(image.name);
          
          setUploadingImage(true)
          imageRef.put(image)
            .then((url) => {
              alert("Successfully uploaded.");
              getFromFirebase();
              setUploadingImage(false)
            })
            .catch(e => setUploadingImage(false));
        } else {
          alert("Please upload an image first.");
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `useEffect`, something like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  document.body.classList.toggle("image-uploading", uploadingImage);
},[uploadingImage])
```

Then add this in your css:

```css
body.image-uploading{
  /* whatever style you want goes here*/
}
```

Comment: thank you - but I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Comment: That’s weird. Check everything is correct, spelling…?

Comment: Everything spelling wise is fine…

Comment: Verify where your scripts are added in  the page. If it’s in `head`  make sure there  is the `defer` attribute.

Comment: @PaulVI can you please tell if it worked?

Comment: No, the classList undefined error is still happening .. still trying to figure it out!

Comment: This is what I have:
const [uploadingImage, setUploadingImage] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.body.classList.toggle("image-uploading", uploadingImage);
  },[uploadingImage])

Comment: As you can see here on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-tereshkova-ck35et?file=/src/App.js), it should work. The background is red because the class is being added. Make sure your browser is up to date. Which one are you using?